# pandas read_csv ignores separator

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with the following text in French:

```
 "Dune!;Jeux"
 "Snapchat;Photo et vidéo"
 "Instagram;Photo et vidéo"
 "YouTube: Regarder & Découvrir;Photo et vidéo"
 "WhatsApp Messenger;Réseaux sociaux"
 "Wish - Acheter en s'amusant;Shopping"
 "Messenger;Réseaux sociaux"
```

I am unable to read this file as two columns using `;` as a separator:

```
df = pd.read_csv("src.csv",delimiter=';',header=None,encoding="latin-1")
print(df.head())
```

It gives the following:

```
                                              0
0                                    Dune!;Jeux
1                       Snapchat;Photo et vidéo
2                      Instagram;Photo et vidéo
3  YouTube: Regarder & Découvrir;Photo et vidéo
4            WhatsApp Messenger;Réseaux sociaux
```

Looks like the `;` as a separator was ignored. What's wrong with my code sample?

Comment: Can you post a link to your raw txt file, there maybe some weird encoding issue, currently this works by copying and pasting this

Comment: here it is: https://pastebin.com/fr623Vez (save it locally in ISO-8859-1 encoding)

Comment: The problem here is that every line is quote enclosed in your txt file

Comment: Hmm... That's the actual data I have. How do I process it?

Comment: need `quoting=3` parameter

Comment: @jezrael that raises a parser error, I think the easiest thing is to either define a converter func to pass to `read_csv` or just post-process using `str.split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be `sep=';'` not `delimeter=';'`:

```
In[41]:
import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', header=None)
df

Out[41]: 
                                0                1
0                           Dune!             Jeux
1                        Snapchat   Photo et vidéo
2                       Instagram   Photo et vidéo
3   YouTube: Regarder & Découvrir   Photo et vidéo
4              WhatsApp Messenger  Réseaux sociaux
5     Wish - Acheter en s'amusant         Shopping
6                       Messenger  Réseaux sociaux
```

**update**

Looking at your data, every line is wrapped in quotations so it's not able to parse this correctly, you could just do this as a post processing step using `.str.split(';',expand=True)`

```
In[61]:
df1 = df[0].str.split(';',expand=True)
df1

Out[61]: 
                                           0                 1     2
0                                      Dune!              Jeux  None
1                                   Snapchat   Photo et vidÃ©o  None
2                                  Instagram   Photo et vidÃ©o  None
3             YouTube: Regarder & DÃ©couvrir   Photo et vidÃ©o  None
4                         WhatsApp Messenger  RÃ©seaux sociaux  None
5                Wish - Acheter en s'amusant          Shopping  None
6                                  Messenger  RÃ©seaux sociaux  None
7                                    Bitmoji       Utilitaires  None
8                 Sonic Forces: Speed Battle              Jeux  None
9                                  Dunk Shot              Jeux  None
10                                  Facebook  RÃ©seaux sociaux  None
11                                   Netflix    Divertissement  None
12                           Super Mario Run              Jeux  None
13       Tu prÃ©fÃ¨res? Â Choix impossibles              Jeux  None
14            Waze - GPS et trafic en direct        Navigation  None
15                            Pro des MotsÂ              Jeux  None
16                                 Bravoloto              Jeux  None
17                                   Groupon          Shopping  None
18                                 Leboncoin       Utilitaires  None
19                             Spotify Music           Musique  None
20                    Molotov - TV en direct            replay  None
21                          Enlight Photofox   Photo et vidÃ©o  None
22                                   Sarahah  RÃ©seaux sociaux  None
23                    Perte de poids Fitness   Forme et santÃ©  None
24                                 Vinted.fr      Style de vie  None
25                   AliExpress Shopping App          Shopping  None
26                                 Amazon FR          Shopping  None
27                   Yuka - Scan de produits   Forme et santÃ©  None
28            Google Maps - GPS & Transports        Navigation  None
29                                      Joom          Shopping  None
..                                       ...               ...   ...
170           MosaLingua Apprendre l'Anglais        Ãducation  None
171                                 Ventusky           MÃ©tÃ©o  None
172                              Guitare Pro              Jeux  None
173                                   Sense.      Style de vie  None
174            Les aventures de Petit Chaton    Divertissement  None
175                              Lumino City              Jeux  None
176                 ARIMOJI by Ariana Grande    Divertissement  None
177                      A Normal Lost Phone              Jeux  None
178                               Tiny Wings              Jeux  None
179                         Rugby Nations 16              Jeux  None
180  Full Fitness : Exercise Workout Trainer   Forme et santÃ©  None
181                                 LetterÂ²              Jeux  None
182    R-Play - Lecture Ã  distance pour PS4    Divertissement  None
183                            Baby Phone 3G      Style de vie  None
184              Runtastic Mountain Bike PRO   Forme et santÃ©  None
185                     Apprendre l'Espagnol        Ãducation  None
186                            Earn to Die 2              Jeux  None
187                               Samorost 3              Jeux  None
188                      Cut the Rope: Magic              Jeux  None
189               Simulateur MÃ©tro de Paris              Jeux  None
190               Plotagraph+ Photo Animator   Photo et vidÃ©o  None
191   LÂOfficiel du SCRABBLEÂ® Dictionnaire      RÃ©fÃ©rences  None
192      VidÃ©o Royal Pro - Ultimate Edition   Photo et vidÃ©o  None
193                Dictionnaire de franÃ§ais      RÃ©fÃ©rences  None
194                             Ana The Game              Jeux  None
195                                 Facetune   Photo et vidÃ©o  None
196                                    FROST              Jeux  None
197                                   Catane              Jeux  None
198                               Punch Kidd              Jeux  None
199             Antidote Mobile Â FranÃ§ais      RÃ©fÃ©rences  None

[200 rows x 3 columns]
```

You can drop that last column using fancy indexing:

```
In[69]:
df1 = df1.loc[:,:1]
df1.head()

Out[69]: 
                                0                 1
0                           Dune!              Jeux
1                        Snapchat   Photo et vidÃ©o
2                       Instagram   Photo et vidÃ©o
3  YouTube: Regarder & DÃ©couvrir   Photo et vidÃ©o
4              WhatsApp Messenger  RÃ©seaux sociaux
```

Comment: @varnie can you post a link to your raw txt file

Comment: @jezrael strange I never used `delimeter`, it looks like there is some other issue with the raw txt file, it works fine if I copy and paste this and read it

Comment: Me too, to much typing ;)